# Как получить картинку заданного размера из API

Tags: python, json, requests

Делаю запрос к api:

```
url = " линк"
headers = {
            "host": "линк",
            "key": "токен" 
          }
querystr = {"id": 9999999}
resp= requests.request("GET", url, heades, querystr)
data = resp.json()
```

И получаю ответ:

```
{
"id": 9999999,
"obj_images:[
        "URL": "https://-тут линк_{size}.jpg",
        "Img.id": 8888888, 
        "sizes":[
                    {
                        "type": 15,
                        "suffix": "z"
                    }
            и тут длинный список размеров
               ]
           ]
}
```

Как теперь получить картинку  выбранного размера?
Документацию по апи найти не смог(перерыл весь их сайт) видимо это что то из очевидных умений, которых у меня нет.

Comment: Если они возвращают Вам URL, то Вы можете скачать картинку по этому адресу

Comment: Формат URL не совсем понятен. Возможно, Вам нужно подставить `suffix`?

Comment: пробовал в поле {size} подставить {"type": 15, "suffix": "z"} вернуло 404

Comment: Попробуйте в полу `size` подставить один из суффиксов, например, `z`

Comment: Большое спасибо! помогло